# Pass a method as a parameter to another method

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, methods, delegates

I am having a method called LoadData which gets data from DataBase and fills a `DataGridView`.

I am using a Stopwatch to measure how long my method takes to finish it's job as below :

```
private void btnLoadData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    LoadData ();
    sw.Stop();
    ShowTakenTime(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

I want something that can do The following :

```
private void MeasureTime(Method m)
{
    var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    m.Invoke();
    sw.Stop();
    ShowTakenTime(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

so that I can pass the LoadData method to it and it does the rest for me.

```
MeasureTime(LoadData());
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a method without parameters and returning void, you can use [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
    private void MeasureTime(Action m)
    {
        var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        m();
        sw.Stop();
        ShowTakenTime(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

If you have some parameters or a return type, use [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, and what if I had parameters?

Comment: As the last question, what if my Func had no parameter but I expected it to return an int?

Comment: In that case just use the Func<int> m = () => { return 42; }; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The `MeasureTime` method in this answer takes an `Action` because it doesn't care. You can wrap any method in a lambda which matches `Action`, as in this example: `MeasureTime(() => { localResult = MethodWithArgsAndRet(localArg1, localArg2, localArg3); });`. The variables called "local" are simply captured by the anonymous function (lambda).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass parameters to your Method `m`, use an Action<...>, for example if you want to pass an int and a string to your Method, use `Action<int,string>`

```
private void MeasureTime(Action<int, string> m)
{
   var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
   sw.Start();
   m(42, "Hello World");
   sw.Stop();
   ShowTakenTime(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

If you need to access the return value of your Method, use Func<...>:

```
private void MeasureTime(Func<int, string, string> m)
{
   var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
   sw.Start();
   var result = m(42, "Hello World");
   sw.Stop();
   ShowTakenTime(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use delegates

```cs
private void MeasureTime(System.Action a)
{
    var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    a();
    sw.Stop();
    ShowTakenTime(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Action because you are not returning anything:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx

```
 MeasureTime(Action action)
 Action act = LoadData;
 act.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 0):

define a delegate in your class with any signature you want:

```
delegate int YourDelegate(string s);
```

a method that get delegate and run it

```
void CallerMethod(YourDelegate method)
{
    int result = method("");
}
```

method is going to pass and is compatible with `YourDelegate`:

```
int MethodToPass(string s)
{
    throw new exception();
}
```

pass `MethodToPass` to `CallerMewthod`:

```
CallerMethod(MethodToPass);
```

also you can instead of declaring a new delegates, you can use predefined `Func<output, inputType1, inputType2, ...>` generic delegate that supports any type of input and output